# Configuring WAMP with external IP

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I've recently reinstalled WAMP and lost my old configuration. I've looked this up but i found no real solution. I have set up port forwarding to 80 and i know my IP adress. But when i go on it (the website has simple wordpress) it says:
Forbidenn
You don't have permission to acesss / on this server.

I know that it's not safe to do this, but I'm gonna run it like this only to test and show it to a few close friends and relatives before I buy hosting.
So how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took hours of googling but I figured it out.

Had to edit the httpd and hosts configuration file inside of wamp the correct way. I've also had to add a host in windows/system32/drivers. More or less it's working now the homepage atleast.